# Why would svytotal be equal to svymean?

Tags: r, survey

This is wrt the `survey` R package.

My svydesign seems fine.. and I'm producing good estimates. It's a 1-level cluster sample design.

I see my finite population as 160 psus. I see my population at 1600 psus.

But when I run `svytotal(~var, design)` it's equivalent to `svymean(~var, design)`.

I see no obvious reason why this would be so.. and the totals are obviously wildly off..

Why would this be happening?

Comment: What do your weights sum to (ie, `sum(weights(design))`?

Comment: Also, can you post a link to your data?

Comment: I can't it's work data. But let me check that. @ThomasLumley

Comment: They sum to 1.. I normalized a weights column. Should I have just used the original scale as it relates to the pop total? @ThomasLumley

Comment: Yes, you need the unnormalised weights for estimating totals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, based on the discussion in comments, the issue is that the weights have been scaled to add to 1.

Since the estimated mean is just the estimated total divided by the sum of the weights (ie, by the estimated population size), they will be the same if the sum of the weights is 1.

Overall scaling of the weights doesn't affect point estimates of means or contrasts of means, including proportions and regression coefficients. It doesn't affect standard errors of means or contrasts of means except through the finite population correction. But it **does** affect estimated totals.

Comment: Thanks.. I completely assumed it was based on the FPC multiplier since the population read completely. Imo this could be improved!

Comment: It's deliberate. If  you *don't* supply weights, they're based on the FPC. If you *do* supply weights, the package trusts you.